# Can a miner remain anonymous?

Tags: security, protocol, privacy, miner-configuration, block-propagation-time

Can you differentiate the miners from the normal clients, by doing some frequency analysis on ip-addresses that announce new blocks? Or will the new block propagate so fast around the network by normal clients that it's impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is trivial for solo miners to use tor to hide IP adresses. This defeats mentioned above frequency analysis attack.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what this frequency analysis technique would do, so this answer corresponds to the second question you asked:

Blockchain.info connects to hundreds of nodes:

- http://www.blockchain.info/connected-nodes

The IP address Blockchain.info shows is the address of one of those nodes that they happened to be connected to which first saw that transaction.  A node where privacy is desired does not allow incoming connections and only connects to trusted nodes that won't violate privacy expectations.

Comment: With frequency analysis I meant just counting for each node how many times it was one of the first to announce a new block. If there is 1 miner and 50 regular nodes, the miner will on average always be faster than nodes that are just relaying. But I guess as soon as the network grows it will be harder and harder, since you can't be connected to all of them at the same time.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to differentiate between block announcement and block announcement relay